# How to connect SAP HANA Tables with SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, hana

So I am using the SAP Web IDE, and I established a connection to a SAP HANA Database with SAP Cloud Connector to SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit, but when I try to access my data in SAP Web IDE I get the following error:

> 403 Forbidden

I was wondering if someone knew if I am setting up the resources incorrectly, or if it has to deal with my certificates, and if anyone knew any good resources I can check to help me with this problem. I tried watching some YouTube videos and Googling the issue to no avail.

Comment: how is this related to sapui5 ? :-)

Comment: I am trying to connect an internal HANA DB to a SAPUI5 Application, and the way I read that you can achieve that is by using Cloud Connector, then creating an on-premise destination in HANA Cloud Cockpit, but something isn't working since I can see that it is connecting, but I can't access any of the resources I want (being data from tables)

Comment: Sorry, my question is "SAPUI5 is a frontend application, how would it be able to connect to HANA?" What is your backend app? Thanks

Comment: ohh, well from what I understand is that once its setup as a destination in the HANA Cloud cockpit, then it should be available to use from the SAP Web IDE. I am actually unsure if I am missing a backend app or something that I need to do to connect to it. I am only an Intern, so I am not too familiar with how SAP HANA connections work, and how to accomplish the connections.

Resource:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9t89Fy4DVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create either an OData or an XSJS service in your HANA DB to serve the data.

Once this service is available, then you can create the relevant configuration in the SAP Cloud Connector to surface the end point in your environment and finally create a destination that will expose this endpoint for consumption in your SAPUI5 application.

SAPUI5 is a frontend framework that can consume data via OData or REST APIs (XSJS is one type).
But SAPUI5 cannot connect directly to your HANA DB and run SQL queries like you would do in Java with JDBC.

Comment: I have done that, and it seems to connect now, but I am having trouble with the CORS I believe. I have looked online a bit, but I am getting the error message for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I was wondering if you knew what I could do to fix it?

Comment: If you have CORS issue, this usually means that your app requires the use of a resource bound to an external URL.

Comment: Therefore I recommend you to use the browser developer tool to monitor which URL is causing the issue and get back to us.